# Create array variable

Tags: jquery, variables, multidimensional-array, jqplot

I wanted to create this kind of output

```
var s1 = [['Sony',7],['Samsung',5],['LG',8]];
```

so that I could use it to pass on my graph as a variable

out from the result of my ajax

```
success: function(data){

    //code to extract the data value here

    var s1= need to create the data here

    $.jqplot('chart',[s1],{ blah blah blah

}
```

"data" in the success function returns this table layout

```
<table id="tblResult">
    <tr class="tblRows">
        <td class="clsPhone">Sony</td><td class="clsRating">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tblRows">
        <td class="clsPhone">Samsung</td><td class="clsRating">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tblRows">
        <td class="clsPhone">LG</td><td class="clsRating">8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

can you please help me create the logic for this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I'm looking for a solution something like the following:

```
var s1;
$(".tblRows").each(function(){
    // here I don't know exactly on what to do
    //s1.push($(".clsPhone").text(),$(".clsRating").text()));
});
// all I wanted is to make the resul s1=[['Sony',7],['Samsung',5],['LG',8]];
```

because jqplot requires this kind of parameter

```
s1=[['Sony',7],['Samsung',5],['LG',8]];
$.jqplot('chart',[s1],{
        renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions:{
            showDataLabels:true,
            dataLabelThreshold:1
        }
    }
});
```

so I'm looking for a way to create a the value for the variable s1 out from the data
could this be possible?

Comment: Do you want to create an array from a HTML table, am i right?

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify server side of returning data?

Comment: So ...  What's the input look like?

Comment: @fabrik, @Ottomanlast, @strager:  Edited my post. Hope it is clear  for you guys :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var s1 = [];
$(".tblRows").each(function(){
    // create a temp array for this row
    var row = [];
    // add the phone and rating as array elements
    row.push($(this).find('.clsPhone').text());
    row.push($(this).find('.clsRating').text());
    // add the temp array to the main array
    s1.push(row);
});
```

Comment: I think you may need to pass $(data) into the initial selector to make it work.  $(".tblRows", $(data))....  This is because the passed in data is not necessarily in the document at this point

Comment: Ahh, when i'd used the variable name `data`, i hadn't seen that it had already been used - I've changed my answer to rename it `row`

Comment: the logic worked for me... getting the selector from the data is not a big issue for me :) Thanks adam

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var row = [];
$(".tblRows").each(function () {
    row.push([$(this).find('.clsPhone').text(),
              $(this).find('.clsRating').text()]);
});

$.jqplot('chart', [row], {
    //... 
});
```