# What syntax do I need to use to add a temporary array to a member of an object that equates to a generic list of string?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550911/create-array-variable), I thought I could declare and assign to an array this way:

```
var _recipients = [];
    if ($('#email1').length > 0) {
        _recipients.push($('#email1').val());
    }
    if ($('#email2').length > 0) {
        _recipients.push($('#email3').val());
    }
    if ($('#email3').length > 0) {
        _recipients.push($('#email3').val());
    }
```

...and then trying to add that array to a member of an object like so:

```
var saveConfigModel = {
    unit: $('#unitsselect').val(),
    scheduleProduceUsage: $('#ckbx_produceusage').is(':checked'),
    scheduleDeliveryPerformance: $('#ckbx_deliveryperformance').is(':checked'),
    scheduleFillRate: $('#ckbx_fillratebycustomer_location').is('checked'),
    schedulePriceCompliance: $('#ckbx_pricecompliance').is('checked'),
    recipients.push(_recipients),
    . . .
```

...but JSLint complains about that last line of code, saying, "*Expected ':' and instead saw '.'.*"

In more context, this last is part of an AJAX call:

```
var saveConfigModel = {
    unit: $('#unitsselect').val(),
    scheduleProduceUsage: $('#ckbx_produceusage').is(':checked'),
    scheduleDeliveryPerformance: $('#ckbx_deliveryperformance').is(':checked'),
    scheduleFillRate: $('#ckbx_fillratebycustomer_location').is('checked'),
    schedulePriceCompliance: $('#ckbx_pricecompliance').is('checked'),
    recipients.push(_recipients),
        generationDayOfMonth: $('#dayofmonthselect').val(),
        generationOrdinal: $('#ordinalselect').val(),
        generationDayOfWeek: $('#dayofweekselect').val(),
        generationWeekOrMonth: $('#weekormonthselect').val(),
        daterangeFromProduceUsage: $('#produsagefrom').val(),
        daterangeToProduceUsage: $('#produsageto').val(),
        daterangeFromDeliveryPerformance: $('#delperffrom').val(),
        daterangeToDeliveryPerformance: $('#delperfto').val(),
        daterangeFromFillRate: $('#fillratefrom').val(),
        daterangeToFillRate: $('#fillrateto').val(),
        daterangeFromPriceCompliance: $('#pricecompliancefrom').val(),
        daterangeToPriceCompliance: $('#pricecomplianceto').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ model: saveConfigModel })
    });
```

...which was working fine when I was just adding one value to "recipients" like so:

```
recipients: $('#email1').val(),
```

In the Model on the server, recipients is a generic list of string:

```
public class UnitConfigVals
{
    . . .
    public List<string> recipients { get; set; }
    . . .
```

What do I need to fix for this array-assigning to work?

Comment: `recipients: _recipients,`

Comment: In the middle of `saveConfigModel` object literal definition you are running a function... namely `recipients.push(_recipients)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
recipients.push(_recipients),
```

to

```
recipients: _recipients
```

your currently calling a function instead of making an assignment.

Side note: you can replace your first code block with

```
var _recipients = $('[id^="email"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().filter(function (y) {
    return y != '';
});
```